# Logged out users are seeing error message "undefined method `leads' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I made a simple app that lets users track their sales leads. Everything works except for the home page for logged out users, who get the error message - undefined method `leads' for nil:NilClass.

The index in the leads controller:

```
  def index
    @leads = current_user.leads.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @leads }
    end
  end
```

The homepage:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <h2>Leads</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <%= link_to 'Add New Lead', new_lead_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<table id="leads" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small">Website</th>
        <th class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small">Email</th>
        <th class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small">Notes</th>
        <th class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small">Last Updated</th>    
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @leads.each do |lead| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to lead.company_name, lead %></td>
        <td><%= lead.contact %></td>
        <td><%= lead.phone %></td>
        <td class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small"><%= lead.website %></td>
        <td class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small"><%= lead.email %></td>
        <td class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small"><%= lead.notes %></td>
        <td class="hidden-tablet hidden-phone hidden-desktop-small"><%= lead.updated_at.strftime("%d %b %y") %></td>    
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<% else %>
<div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>Welcome to SnapLeads</h1>
    <p>
        The simplest CRM ever.
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= link_to "Sign up now!", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
    </p>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Why would the page be trying to access the leads method if the user is logged out?

Comment: Because the controller calls `leads` on `current_user`, which may be nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the code in your index action is always executed. You could use something like the following in your controller:

```
  def index
    @leads = current_user ? current_user.leads.all : nil

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @leads }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Or just `@leads = current_user.leads.all if current_user`, since the view doesn't use `@leads` if they're not logged in. Whether or not that kind of logic belongs in the view is a separate issue.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Dave and ramblex, that makes sense. This is my first app I've built from scratch so still lots to learn.